Command manager not available- Cannot run Move-to-start
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
ROS distro: Humble
Libfranka 0.13.2
Franka_ROS2
Preempt_RT enabled
Hi, I was following the tutorial link to run ros2 launch franka_bringup move_to_start_example_controller.launch.py robot_ip:=172.16.0.2
I wasn’t too sure what is the error, but it states that controller manager is unavailable. Hence, I ran ‘sudo apt-get install ros-humble-controller-manager’ successfully, but the error still persists.
Error:
onghui@ece-cdl-ts10:~/franka_ros2_ws$ ros2 launch franka_bringup move_to_start_example_controller.launch.py robot_ip:=172.16.0.2
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/yonghui/.ros/log/2024-06-06-11-57-04-131533-ece-cdl-ts10.ece.ubc.ca-10452
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [10455]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [10457]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-3]: process started with pid [10459]
[INFO] [spawner-4]: process started with pid [10461]
[INFO] [spawner-5]: process started with pid [10463]
[INFO] [franka_gripper_node-6]: process started with pid [10465]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [10467]
[franka_gripper_node-6] [INFO] [1717700224.451158233] [panda_gripper]: Trying to establish a connection with the gripper
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1717700224.455231625] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment panda_hand
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1717700224.455303499] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment panda_hand_tcp
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1717700224.455307444] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment panda_leftfinger
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1717700224.455309552] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment panda_link0
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1717700224.455311427] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment panda_link1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1717700224.455313160] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment panda_link2
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1717700224.455314880] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment panda_link3
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1717700224.455316674] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment panda_link4
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1717700224.455318417] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment panda_link5
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1717700224.455320181] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment panda_link6
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1717700224.455322010] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment panda_link7
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1717700224.455323773] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment panda_link8
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1717700224.455325476] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment panda_rightfinger
[ros2_control_node-3] [WARN] [1717700224.459924276] [controller_manager]: [Deprecated] Passing the robot description parameter directly to the control_manager node is deprecated. Use '~/robot_description' topic from 'robot_state_publisher' instead.
[ros2_control_node-3] [INFO] [1717700224.460095002] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'FrankaHardwareInterface' 
[ros2_control_node-3] [INFO] [1717700224.462473746] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'FrankaHardwareInterface' 
[ros2_control_node-3] [INFO] [1717700224.462499695] [FrankaHardwareInterface]: Connecting to robot at "172.16.0.2" ...
[joint_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1717700224.722106061] [joint_state_publisher]: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic...
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1717700226.720304335] [spawner_move_to_start_example_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1717700226.720441018] [spawner_franka_robot_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1717700226.723952073] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1717700228.742376123] [spawner_franka_robot_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1717700228.742379466] [spawner_move_to_start_example_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1717700228.744921298] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1717700230.763954418] [spawner_franka_robot_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1717700230.764165935] [spawner_move_to_start_example_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1717700230.766185269] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1717700232.785574386] [spawner_move_to_start_example_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1717700232.787188738] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1717700232.788051174] [spawner_franka_robot_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-7] [ERROR] [1717700234.808046477] [spawner_move_to_start_example_controller]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-5] [ERROR] [1717700234.810203167] [spawner_franka_robot_state_broadcaster]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-4] [ERROR] [1717700234.810316433] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-4]: process has died [pid 10461, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_broadcaster --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner-5]: process has died [pid 10463, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner franka_robot_state_broadcaster --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner-7]: process has died [pid 10467, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner move_to_start_example_controller --ros-args'].
[franka_gripper_node-6] [FATAL] [1717700284.478872718] [panda_gripper]: libfranka: Connection timeout. Please check your network connection or settings.
[franka_gripper_node-6] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'franka::Exception'
[franka_gripper_node-6]   what():  libfranka: Connection timeout. Please check your network connection or settings.
[ERROR] [franka_gripper_node-6]: process has died [pid 10465, exit code -6, cmd '/home/yonghui/franka_ros2_ws/install/franka_gripper/lib/franka_gripper/franka_gripper_node --ros-args -r __node:=panda_gripper --params-file /tmp/launch_params_nkkvkfl5 --params-file /home/yonghui/franka_ros2_ws/install/franka_gripper/share/franka_gripper/config/franka_gripper_node.yaml'].
[ros2_control_node-3] [FATAL] [1717700284.562758658] [FrankaHardwareInterface]: Could not connect to robot
[ros2_control_node-3] [FATAL] [1717700284.562785395] [FrankaHardwareInterface]: libfranka: Connection timeout. Please check your network connection or settings.
[ros2_control_node-3] [INFO] [1717700284.562804987] [resource_manager]: Failed to initialize hardware 'FrankaHardwareInterface'
[ros2_control_node-3] [WARN] [1717700284.562808124] [resource_manager]: System hardware component 'FrankaHardwareInterface' from plugin 'franka_hardware/FrankaHardwareInterface' failed to initialize.
[ros2_control_node-3] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[ros2_control_node-3]   what():  Wrong state or command interface configuration.
[ros2_control_node-3] missing state interfaces:
[ros2_control_node-3] ' panda_joint1/position ' ' panda_joint1/velocity '   ' panda_joint1/effort ' ' panda_joint2/position '   ' panda_joint2/velocity '   ' panda_joint2/effort ' ' panda_joint3/position '   ' panda_joint3/velocity '   ' panda_joint3/effort ' ' panda_joint4/position '   ' panda_joint4/velocity '   ' panda_joint4/effort ' ' panda_joint5/position '   ' panda_joint5/velocity '   ' panda_joint5/effort ' ' panda_joint6/position '   ' panda_joint6/velocity '   ' panda_joint6/effort ' ' panda_joint7/position '   ' panda_joint7/velocity '   ' panda_joint7/effort ' 
[ros2_control_node-3] missing command interfaces:
[ros2_control_node-3] ' panda_joint1/effort '   ' panda_joint1/velocity '   ' panda_joint1/position '   ' panda_joint2/effort ' ' panda_joint2/velocity '   ' panda_joint2/position '   ' panda_joint3/effort ' ' panda_joint3/velocity '   ' panda_joint3/position '   ' panda_joint4/effort ' ' panda_joint4/velocity '   ' panda_joint4/position '' panda_joint5/effort '    ' panda_joint5/velocity '   ' panda_joint5/position '   ' panda_joint6/effort ' ' panda_joint6/velocity '   ' panda_joint6/position '   ' panda_joint7/effort ' ' panda_joint7/velocity '   ' panda_joint7/position '   
[ros2_control_node-3] Stack trace (most recent call last):
[ros2_control_node-3] #15   Object "", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #14   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x558defef3d84, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #13   Source "../csu/libc-start.c", line 392, in __libc_start_main_impl [0x7f190c608e3f]
[ros2_control_node-3] #12   Source "../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h", line 58, in __libc_start_call_main [0x7f190c608d8f]
[ros2_control_node-3] #11   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x558defef389e, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #10   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libcontroller_manager.so", at 0x7f190ccfce79, in controller_manager::ControllerManager::ControllerManager(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rclcpp::NodeOptions const&)
[ros2_control_node-3] #9    Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libcontroller_manager.so", at 0x7f190ccf86bf, in controller_manager::ControllerManager::init_resource_manager(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
[ros2_control_node-3] #8    Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7f190c50bf1c, in hardware_interface::ResourceManager::load_urdf(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool)
[ros2_control_node-3] #7    Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7f190c4e85dd, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #6    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f190c8d64d7, in __cxa_throw
[ros2_control_node-3] #5    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f190c8d6276, in std::terminate()
[ros2_control_node-3] #4    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f190c8d620b, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #3    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f190c8cab9d, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #2    Source "./stdlib/abort.c", line 79, in abort [0x7f190c6077f2]
[ros2_control_node-3] #1    Source "../sysdeps/posix/raise.c", line 26, in raise [0x7f190c621475]
[ros2_control_node-3] #0  | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 89, in __pthread_kill_internal
[ros2_control_node-3]     | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 78, in __pthread_kill_implementation
[ros2_control_node-3]       Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 44, in __pthread_kill [0x7f190c6759fc]
[ros2_control_node-3] Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 10459 1000)
[ERROR] [ros2_control_node-3]: process has died [pid 10459, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_43av52be --params-file /home/yonghui/franka_ros2_ws/install/franka_bringup/share/franka_bringup/config/controllers.yaml -r joint_states:=franka/joint_states'].
[INFO] [launch]: process[ros2_control_node-3] was required: shutting down launched system
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-2]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[joint_state_publisher-2]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[robot_state_publisher-1]
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1717700285.674801554] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 10455]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 10457]


Launch file:
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, PathJoinSubstitution
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare

def generate_launch_description():
robot_ip_parameter_name = ‘robot_ip’
load_gripper_parameter_name = ‘load_gripper’
use_fake_hardware_parameter_name = ‘use_fake_hardware’
fake_sensor_commands_parameter_name = ‘fake_sensor_commands’
use_rviz_parameter_name = ‘use_rviz’
robot_ip = LaunchConfiguration(robot_ip_parameter_name)
load_gripper = LaunchConfiguration(load_gripper_parameter_name)
use_fake_hardware = LaunchConfiguration(use_fake_hardware_parameter_name)
fake_sensor_commands = LaunchConfiguration(fake_sensor_commands_parameter_name)
use_rviz = LaunchConfiguration(use_rviz_parameter_name)

return LaunchDescription(
    [
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            robot_ip_parameter_name, description='Hostname or IP address of the robot.'
        ),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            use_rviz_parameter_name,
            default_value='false',
            description='Visualize the robot in Rviz',
        ),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            use_fake_hardware_parameter_name,
            default_value='false',
            description='Use fake hardware',
        ),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            fake_sensor_commands_parameter_name,
            default_value='false',
            description='Fake sensor commands. Only valid when "{}" is true'.format(
                use_fake_hardware_parameter_name
            ),
        ),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            load_gripper_parameter_name,
            default_value='true',
            description=(
                'Use Franka Gripper as an end-effector, otherwise, the robot is loaded '
                'without an end-effector.'
            ),
        ),
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
                [
                    PathJoinSubstitution(
                        [FindPackageShare('franka_bringup'), 'launch', 'franka.launch.py']
                    )
                ]
            ),
            launch_arguments={
                robot_ip_parameter_name: robot_ip,
                load_gripper_parameter_name: load_gripper,
                use_fake_hardware_parameter_name: use_fake_hardware,
                fake_sensor_commands_parameter_name: fake_sensor_commands,
                use_rviz_parameter_name: use_rviz,
            }.items(),
        ),
        **Node(
            package='controller_manager',
            executable='spawner',
            arguments=['move_to_start_example_controller'],
            output='screen',**
        ),
    ]
)

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(franka_bringup)

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)

install(
  DIRECTORY config launch
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()

Controllers.yaml:
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 1000  # Hz

    gravity_compensation_example_controller:
      type: franka_example_controllers/GravityCompensationExampleController

    joint_impedance_example_controller:
      type: franka_example_controllers/JointImpedanceExampleController

    joint_velocity_example_controller:
      type: franka_example_controllers/JointVelocityExampleController

    joint_position_example_controller:
      type: franka_example_controllers/JointPositionExampleController

    cartesian_velocity_example_controller:
      type: franka_example_controllers/CartesianVelocityExampleController
    
    cartesian_pose_example_controller:
      type: franka_example_controllers/CartesianPoseExampleController

    cartesian_pose_elbow_example_controller:
      type: franka_example_controllers/CartesianElbowExampleController

    joint_impedance_with_ik_example_controller:
      type: franka_example_controllers/JointImpedanceWithIKExampleController

    cartesian_orientation_example_controller:
      type: franka_example_controllers/CartesianOrientationExampleController

    elbow_example_controller:
      type: franka_example_controllers/ElbowExampleController

    move_to_start_example_controller:
      type: franka_example_controllers/MoveToStartExampleController

    model_example_controller:
      type: franka_example_controllers/ModelExampleController

    joint_trajectory_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
    
    franka_robot_state_broadcaster:
      type: franka_robot_state_broadcaster/FrankaRobotStateBroadcaster

joint_impedance_with_ik_example_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    arm_id: panda
    k_gains:
      - 600.0
      - 600.0
      - 600.0
      - 600.0
      - 250.0
      - 150.0
      - 50.0
    d_gains:
      - 30.0
      - 30.0
      - 30.0
      - 30.0
      - 10.0
      - 10.0
      - 5.

franka_robot_state_broadcaster:
  ros__parameters:
    arm_id: panda

model_example_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    arm_id: panda

joint_trajectory_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - panda_joint1
      - panda_joint2
      - panda_joint3
      - panda_joint4
      - panda_joint5
      - panda_joint6
      - panda_joint7
    command_interfaces:
      - effort
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity
    gains:
      panda_joint1: { p: 600., d: 30., i: 0., i_clamp: 1. }
      panda_joint2: { p: 600., d: 30., i: 0., i_clamp: 1. }
      panda_joint3: { p: 600., d: 30., i: 0., i_clamp: 1. }
      panda_joint4: { p: 600., d: 30., i: 0., i_clamp: 1. }
      panda_joint5: { p: 250., d: 10., i: 0., i_clamp: 1. }
      panda_joint6: { p: 150., d: 10., i: 0., i_clamp: 1. }
      panda_joint7: { p: 50., d: 5., i: 0., i_clamp: 1. }

joint_impedance_example_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    arm_id: panda
    k_gains:
      - 24.0
      - 24.0
      - 24.0
      - 24.0
      - 10.0
      - 6.0
      - 2.0
    d_gains:
      - 2.0
      - 2.0
      - 2.0
      - 1.0
      - 1.0
      - 1.0
      - 0.5
move_to_start_example_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    arm_id: panda
    k_gains:
      - 600.0
      - 600.0
      - 600.0
      - 600.0
      - 250.0
      - 150.0
      - 50.0
    d_gains:
      - 30.0
      - 30.0
      - 30.0
      - 30.0
      - 10.0
      - 10.0
      - 5.

Please help me, I am so stuck!! Thank you!

Please format your question (use code blocks) and also add the full console output.

@ChristophFroehlich Oops sorry I am new to this community. Code block and output are both added. Thanks for letting me know!

See the error from your hardware component libfranka: Connection timeout. It can't be initialized, and that's why the controller manager services aren't available yet and the spawners die (you could increase the timeout of the spawners, but the problem seems to be the network to your robot).
